# How to count co-prime to n in a range [1,x] where x can be different from n?

Tags: c++, algorithm, primes

I want to count co-primes of n in a range [1,x]. I have tried using euler phi function but it gives for [1,n].Can anyone suggest a modification to euler phi or any other approach to do this?
I have used phi(n) = n* product of (1-(1/p)) where p is a prime factor of n.

Comment: How large are n and x?

Comment: You can use a sieve. See http://programmingpraxis.com/2012/07/10/sieving-for-totients/ for the solution to a similar problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)**

Find the unique prime factors of N (they cannot be more than 10-12, Considering N and X <=10^10).

Now you can find the number of numbers <=x and divisible by 'y' just by dividing. Try all combination of factors of n for y **(you will get only 2^10 (1024) in worst case**).
Use Inclusion Exclusion now to find the co-primes of n less than x.

> The idea is that if a number is not co-prime to n, then it will have
> at least one prime factor common with n.

For our example here lets consider X=35 and N=30

1. First find the  unique prime factor of the number. (their number must not be greater than 10-12).  Unique Prime factor of N ={2,3,5}.
2. Find the product of each factor **PAIR**. {2x3, 2x5, 3x5 or 6, 10, 15}.
3. Find the product of each factor **TRIPLET**: { 2x3x5 or 30}.
4. Repeat until all factors are multiplied together: {N=30 and no more steps are required}.
5. Find the sum of X divided by each factor from STEP 1: {X=35: (35/2)+(35/3)+(35/5) = (17+11+7)=35}
6. Find the sum of X divided by each number from STEP 2: {X=35: 35/65+3+2=10}
7. Find the sum of X divided by each number from STEP 3: {X=35: 1}
8. Repeat until all results from step 4 are absorbed: {x=35 no more steps are required}
9. Number of co-primes to N in the range [1..X] = X - step5 + step6 - step7 etc. {N=30, X=35 is given by 35 - 35 + 10 - 1 = 9}.

> For N=30, X=60 you will have:
>
> 60 - (60/2 + 60/3 + 60/5) + (60/6 + 60/10+ 60/15) - (60/30) = 60 -
> (30+20+12) + (10+6+4) - 2 = 60 -62 + 20 - 2 = 16.

Suppose X = 10. N = 6 = 2 * 3.

We have the numbers {1, 2, 3, ..., 10}.

Remove all multiples of 2. You get: {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}.

Remove all multiples of 3. You get: {1, 5, 7}.

How do we count this efficiently? Try answering this question: How many numbers are there in [1, X] that are divisible by p? It's Floor(X/p), right? i.e., p, 2p, ..., kp, where kp <= X. So, from X, we can subtract Floor(X/p),
and you will get the number of numbers that are relatively prime to p in [1, X].

In this example, there are 10 numbers. Number of numbers divisible by 2 is 10/2, which is 5. So, 10-5 = 5 numbers are relatively prime to 2. Similary, there are 10/3=3 numbers which are multiples of 3. So, can we say that there are 5-3=2 numbers that are relatively prime to 2 and 3? No. Because you have double counted! Why? 6 has been included in the count for p = 2 and 3. So we have to account for this by adding multiples of 2 and 3. There is only one multiple of 2 and 3 in [1, 10], which is 6. So, add 1. Which means, the answer is 10 - 5 - 3 + 1 = 3, which is right.

The generalisation of this is the inclusion and exclusion principle.  For every n, we are just finding its prime factors, which I know for sure will be less than 10 or so. This is done using the Sieve of Eratosthenes, followed by a prime factorisation. (since X < 10^9, the maximum number of prime factors a number will have is less. Try finding out the product of the first 10 primes. It will be: 6469693230, which is about ~ 64*10^9.(i consider max limit as 10^10. this can be easily extended to big numbers like 10^18.)

i hope this helps !!

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.... but i still have one question how to implelement step 6,7 in c++

Comment: see. calculate pair , triplet and just do integer division and take sum of all! try coding it ! else i will help you! 
Just drop the comment here i will post the hint for code !